# How to activate full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to activate full screen mode using Javascript but it is not working.

Please note that console logs inside the function (on line 4 and 11) are printing correct values but full screen mode is not appearing.

what might be the issue? Here's my code.

```
function fullscreen()
{
    var _element = document.getElementById('BookMainDiv');
    console.log(_element);
    if (_element.mozRequestFullScreen)
    {
        _element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(_element.webkitRequestFullScreen)
    {
        console.log("aaa");
       _element.webkitRequestFullScreen();  
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="BookMainDiv" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:yellow">
</div>
<input type="button" style="height:20%;width:20%" onclick="fullscreen()">
</body>
```

p.s. I am using chrome 31 on windows 8

Comment: How is `fullscreen` being invoked?

Comment: _element.webkitRequestFullScreen();

Comment: I mean, are you trying from console? (It won't work, you need the page to fire it, something to do with origin)

Comment: lol no, i am just printing console logs to see if i am getting correct values and functions are working properly, i am not trying to invoke full screen from console

Comment: i do have a html page and i am using button (onclick) to fire it

Comment: As I understand, it is not possible to achieve this in an easy way. Every browser handels this completly different. Some browsers (like chrome if I remember correctly) even block that from javascript.

Comment: @RononDex any way to fix it? according to mdn it should work perfectly on chrome and firefox

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: Doesn't the `BookMainDiv` happen to be inside the iframe, does it?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe yes, [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: @dmedvinsky no i am not using iframe,

Comment: Well, you should provide more code context, then.

Comment: @sabotero html code is added now

Comment: Developers Tools are open in your chrome and have you breakpoints?

Comment: your code is working for me. Do you have JavaScript errors in console?

Comment: how are you declaring your html document?

Comment: no i don't have any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function fullscreen()
      {
        var fullscrn = document.getElementById("BookMainDiv");
        req= fullscrn.requestFullScreen || fullscrn.webkitRequestFullScreen || fullscrn.mozRequestFullScreen;
        req.call(fullscrn);


      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="BookMainDiv" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:yellow">
    </div>
    <input type="button" style="height:20%;width:20%" onclick="fullscreen()">
  </body>

</html>
```

**P.S:Your code is working fine in my system , (yes, browser is chrome itself)**

Comment: sorry cant test your code atm,i will test it tomorrow morning, Indian time will respond after that

Answer (score 0):

It happens that the `requesFullScreen` (`webkitRequestFullScreen`) does not work in Chrome when developper tools are open and you have break points in the javascript!
Close it and you will see it will work!

----------------------------- EDITED ------------------

Be sure your document declaration is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And try this code :

```
function FullScreen() {
    var element = document.getElementById("BookMainDiv");
    if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    }
    if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so is really weird. If you open your developper tools do you have erros in console?